# Xcode: How to add an integer to a NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

im kind of a noob on objective c and still are having trouble with some basics, in this case
I'm developing a pdf viewer on xcode, but im having a problem adding a integer to my NSUrl variable.

I have several pdf's on my site:

> "http://mysite.com/1.pdf" "2.pdf" etc.

but the number of pdf files allways change so in order to avoid using a NSMutableArray with all the url sites what im trying to make is a NSURL variable like this:

`int numpag = 1;

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://mysite.com/%d.pdf", numpag;

[pdfView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress]]];`

is there a correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try;

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/%d.pdf",numpag];
```

Comment: Excelent seems i was missing the `stringWithFormat`
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
int numpag = 1;
NSString *baseURLStr = @"http://mysite.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURLStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.pdf", numpag]];
```

Comment: Wow! this one is verry usefull if you intend to change the folder in the baseURL!

Comment: Change folder? I don't understand. Nothing wrong with @Roger's answer, but mine is more complete, if you want a NSURL object.

Comment: Yes! your answer is very complete!
When i mean change folder is because i have an if condition telling the app "if there is a 2.pdf on this folder load it, else change folder and load 1.pdf and so forth!